Using intersection observer instead of windows.onscroll
I have built a data grid that renders millions of data. it depends on virtualization/windowing and onscroll event to render only visible cells. I need to use intersection observer instead of onscroll.
I tried a lot to do that, but my virtualization deeply depend on the scrolling event.
Here is my code
const Datatable = ({
  cellWidth = 120,
  cellHeight = 25,
  rowBuffer = 2,
  columnBuffer = 2,
  onCellRightClick,
  fetchDebounceDelay = 300,
  updateDebounceDelay = 500,
  rowsPerFetch = 500,
  columnsPerFetch = 5,
  fetchCells,
  updateCell,
}: Props) => {
  // Buffer cannot be negative
  rowBuffer = rowBuffer < 0 ? 0 : rowBuffer;
  columnBuffer = columnBuffer < 0 ? 0 : columnBuffer;

  // State
  const [tableElement, setTableElement] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState<CellType[][]>([]); // Cell[row][col]
  const [activeCell, setActiveCell] = useState<{ row: number; col: number } | null>(null);
  const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = useState(0);
  const [nextRow, setNextRow] = useState<number | null>(0);
  const [columnLimit, setColumnLimit] = useState(columnsPerFetch);
  const [nextColumn, setNextColumn] = useState<number | null>(columnsPerFetch);
  const [parentSize, setParentSize] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState({ top: 0, left: 0 });

  // Virtualization
  const rowCount = grid.length;
  const columnCount = getColumnCount(grid);

  const visibleRowCount = Math.ceil(parentSize.height / cellHeight);
  const visibleColumnCount = Math.ceil(parentSize.width / cellWidth);

  const startRow = Math.max(Math.floor(scrollPosition.top / cellHeight) - rowBuffer, 0);
  const endRow = Math.min(startRow + visibleRowCount + rowBuffer, rowCount);

  const startColumn = Math.max(Math.floor(scrollPosition.left / cellWidth) - columnBuffer, 0);
  const endColumn = Math.min(startColumn + visibleColumnCount + columnBuffer, columnCount);

  const visibleRows = Array.from({ length: endRow - startRow }, (_, i) => startRow + i);
  const visibleColumns = Array.from({ length: endColumn - startColumn }, (_, i) => startColumn + i);

  // Handlers

  const getCell = (row: number, column: number): CellType | undefined => grid[row]?.[column];

  const handleUpdateCell = async (id: number, updateCellInput: UpdateCellInput) => {
    // Make a request to update the cell via the service
    const updatedCell = await updateCell(id, updateCellInput);
    const { row, col } = updatedCell;

    // Update the local state with the new cell information
    setGrid((prev) => {
      const updatedCells = [...prev];
      if (!updatedCells[row]) {
        updatedCells[row] = [];
      }
      updatedCells[row] = updatedCells[row].map((cell) => (cell.id === updatedCell.id ? updatedCell : cell));
      updatedCells[row][col] = updatedCell;
      return updatedCells;
    });

    // Return the updated cell after state update
    return updatedCell;
  };

  const handleFetchCells = async (paginationDirection: PaginationDirection) => {
    const { vertical = false, horizontal = false } = paginationDirection;

    // Get pagination params
    if ((!vertical && !horizontal) || (vertical && horizontal)) return false;
    if (vertical && nextRow === null) return false;
    if (horizontal && nextColumn === null) return false;
    if (rowsPerFetch === 0 || columnLimit === 0) return false;

    const paginationParams = horizontal
      ? {
          rowLimit: rowsPerFetch + currentRow,
          colLimit: columnLimit,
          nextRow: 0,
          nextCol: nextColumn as number,
        }
      : {
          rowLimit: rowsPerFetch,
          colLimit: columnLimit,
          nextRow: nextRow as number,
          nextCol: 0,
        };

    try {
      // Fetch Cells from the backend
      const response = await fetchCells(paginationParams);
      const { cells: fetchedCells, ...meta } = response;

      // Update the cells state
      setGrid((prev) => {
        const updatedCells = [...prev];
        fetchedCells.forEach((cell) => {
          // Create row if not exist
          if (!updatedCells[cell.row]) {
            updatedCells[cell.row] = [];
          }

          // No cell duplicates
          if (updatedCells[cell.row].find((prevCell) => prevCell.id === cell.id)) {
            return;
          }

          // Add fetched cell into its row
          updatedCells[cell.row] = updatedCells[cell.row].concat(cell);
        });
        return updatedCells;
      });

      // Update pagination state
      if (vertical) {
        if (nextRow !== null) {
          setCurrentRow(() => nextRow);
          setNextRow(meta.nextRow);
        } else {
          setNextRow(null);
        }
      }
      if (horizontal) {
        if (nextColumn !== null) {
          setColumnLimit(columnsPerFetch * 2);
          setNextColumn(meta.nextCol);
        } else {
          setNextColumn(null);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch cells: ${error}`);
    }
  };

  const debouncedFetchMore = useMemo(
    () => debounce(handleFetchCells, fetchDebounceDelay),
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [fetchDebounceDelay, nextRow, nextColumn, rowsPerFetch, columnsPerFetch]
  );

  // Effects

  // ...cut off

  // Handle Scrolling
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!tableElement) return;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      // Get the current scroll positions
      const currentScrollTop = tableElement.scrollTop;
      const currentScrollLeft = tableElement.scrollLeft;

      // Determine the scrolling direction
      const isVerticalScroll = currentScrollTop !== scrollPosition.top;
      const isHorizontalScroll = currentScrollLeft !== scrollPosition.left;

      // Update the scroll state
      setScrollPosition(() => ({ top: currentScrollTop, left: currentScrollLeft }));

      // Calculate fetch parameters based on scroll position
      const { scrollHeight, scrollWidth, clientHeight, clientWidth } = tableElement;
      const paginationDirection = { vertical: false, horizontal: false };
      // Calculate the scroll percentages
      const verticalScrollPercentage = (scrollPosition.top + clientHeight) / scrollHeight;
      const horizontalScrollPercentage = (scrollPosition.left + clientWidth) / scrollWidth;

      // Define scroll thresholds
      const scrollAtBottom = verticalScrollPercentage >= 0.85; // Near the bottom of the scrollable area
      const scrollAtRight = horizontalScrollPercentage >= 0.85; // Near the right edge of the scrollable area

      // Case 1: Scroll Down & Right
      if (scrollAtBottom && scrollAtRight && isVerticalScroll && isHorizontalScroll) {
        paginationDirection.vertical = true;
        paginationDirection.horizontal = true;
      }

      // Case 2: Scroll Down
      if (scrollAtBottom && isVerticalScroll) {
        paginationDirection.vertical = true;
      }

      // Case 3: Scroll Right
      if (scrollAtRight && isHorizontalScroll) {
        paginationDirection.horizontal = true;
      }

      // Call the debounced fetch function if parameters are valid
      if (!(paginationDirection.vertical && paginationDirection.horizontal)) {
        debouncedFetchMore(paginationDirection);
      }
    };

    tableElement.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      tableElement.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [debouncedFetchMore, scrollPosition.left, scrollPosition.top, tableElement]);

  // ... cut off

  // Do not render if there is no data
  if (!rowCount && !columnCount) return null;

  // Render virtualized cells with their actual values
  return (
    <div className={styles.table} role="table" ref={(ref) => setTableElement(ref)}>
      <div
        className={styles.container}
        style={{
          width: cellWidth * columnCount,
          height: cellHeight * rowCount,
        }}
      >
        {visibleRows.map((row) =>
          visibleColumns.map((col) => {
            const cell = getCell(row, col);

            if (!cell) return null;

            return (
              <Cell
                key={cell.id}
                cell={cell}
                cellWidth={cellWidth}
                cellHeight={cellHeight}
                debounceDelay={updateDebounceDelay}
                updateCell={handleUpdateCell}
                activateCell={activateCell}
                isActiveCell={isActiveCell}
                onCellRightClick={onCellRightClick}
              />
            );
          })
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


I tried to remove onscroll event and used intersection observer to fetch data when almost reaching the last row/column, but this lead to break my virtualization.
